# How can I set the IWorkspace root?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am new in JDT. I am working in a plug-in where I have to get all projects in the workspace, but I also need to get other workspace projects to then extract information to compare it.

So for the first one I'd get it through:

```java
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    IProject[] projects = root.getProjects();
```

Does somebody know how can I get the other resource? Or how can I set root using same syntax?

Comment: If you mean projects in other workspaces you can't access those using `IProject`.

Comment: Ok, then how could I?

Comment: There are no APIs for accessing projects in other workspaces. What sort of information do you want to access?

Comment: I am getting imports from source code of projects... but I need to compare the information from current workspace and other projects that are in other source. So I though in that way was possible, but then I will have to think in other way to do it.